# Calculating/cutting and pasting a container field

Tags: filemaker

I am in the process of combining several tables into one larger table in Filemaker (they should not have been multiple tables in the first place). I can pull all the numbers/text without problems (via `if(isFromTableA);takeFromA;if(isFromTableB);takeFromB;...)..)`). *I had the hope that I could remove the smaller tables but this is looking unlikely due to unstored data.*

However when attempting this for container fields (e.g. a picture), it returns `0`, how can I make this include the actual picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is wrong with your formula or script or field/result types, perhaps. Container fields can be manipulated freely, except that they're almost completely opaque. But you can make formulas that return containers, place them into variables, pass to scripts as parameters, or import them between tables; all this should work.

Comment: I just had to ensure the new field I was importing to was of the correct type i.e. a container. (oops!)